# CSS: td tag removed from table, a little space remains

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, space, css-tables

I've been trying to mess around with my MAL CSS (myanimelist) to my liking. I've encountered this weird behavior in webkit browsers like chrome and opera where an extra space is left when I reposition a td element.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I made a jsfiddle for the project, where I basically copy pasted some html code from my anime list and slapped in my CSS code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qwwtt/1/

So what I exactly did was I removed a td element from where it's supposed to be, then repositioned it and added position:fixed and display:block so I could freely move it around. Now the thing is, it leaves a space on it's table location when viewed with Chrome or Opera. Here's the CSS code of the table rows and cells. (td:nth-of-type(6) is the one I repositioned)

```
tr [class^=td] {
    background-color: rgba(64,64,64,0);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease, border-color 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease, border-color 1s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s ease, border-color 1s ease;
    transition: background-color 2s ease, border-color 1s ease;
}

tr:hover [class^=td] {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
}

tr td[class^=td] {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

/**
*
* Per-column CSS
*
**/

tr td:nth-of-type(1)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(1)[class=table_header] {
    width: 4%;
    min-width: 35px;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(2)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(2)[class=table_header] {
    min-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(3)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(3)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(4)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(4)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(5)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(5)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(7)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(7)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(8)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(8)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(9)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(9)[class=table_header],
tr td:nth-of-type(10)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(10)[class=table_header] {
    width: 8%;
    min-width: 75px;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(6)[class^=td], tr td:nth-of-type(6)[class=table_header] {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,50px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,50px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px,50px);
    transform: translate(0px,50px);
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-out;
    transition: 1s ease-out;

    padding: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-align: justify;
}

tr:hover td:nth-of-type(6)[class^=td] {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated- but I weirdly find myself quite liking what you've produced here design-wise

Comment: "weirdly"? xD haha thanks, but it's just a copy paste from [my animelist](http://myanimelist.net/animelist/JeMhUnTeR) so I didn't really do anything but the css codes :D